# Type Error when Lemmatizing words using NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, wordnet, lemmatization

I have parsed 30 excel files and created a pandas dataframe. I have tokenized the words, taken out stop words and made bigrams. However when I try to lemmatize it gives me this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Here's my code:

```
# Use simple pre-proces to clean up data and tokenize
def sent_to_words(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
    yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))

data_words = list(sent_to_words(data))

# Define Function for Removing stopwords
def remove_stopwords(texts):
    return[[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts]

# Define function for bigrams
def make_bigrams(texts):
    return[bigram_mod[doc] for doc in texts]

#Remove Stop Words
data_words_nostops = remove_stopwords(data_words)
# Form Bigrams
data_words_bigrams = make_bigrams(data_words_nostops)

#Define function for lemmatizing
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
def get_lemma(word):
    return WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word)

#Lemmatize words
data_lemmatized = get_lemma(data_words_bigrams)
```

This is exactly where I get the error. How should I adjust my code to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance

as suggested, the first few lines of the dataframe

```
df.head()
```

[dataframe snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbIb8.png)

Comment: It looks as if you pass a list to `WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize()`, but it only takes strings as input. If you post a sample of your DataFrame (e.g. the output of `df.head()`), it would be much easier to help. Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice.

Comment: thank you Wolfgangk for the suggestion. I have added png of df.head().

Comment: Thanks for your response. You posted a screenshot of a dataframe (next time please copy and paste your data as text). What is the name of that dataframe in your code? What exactly (show data!) are you passing to the `get_lemma` function?